# alternative to DOMSubtreeModified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, i have a code in javascript where it use the DOMSubtreeModified function. But this is cause an infinite loop in IE. What is the best alternative?

```
    $(".currency").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function (el) {
    if (_formatingMoney) return;

    _formatingMoney = true;

    try{
        if ($(el.target).text().trim().length != 0) {
            $(el.target).formatMoney();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERRO: FormatingMoney: " + err);
    } finally {
        _formatingMoney = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified), this event has been deprecated, replaced by [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: But how i can transforme this to use MutationObserver? I'm sorry but javascript is confused for me. I need to redo the whole function, right?